# MySQL count complex query results

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a query to know how many times the value of a field is repeated in a select?

I prove with:
$queryIds ="select id,idpol,count(idpol) as qid from table WHERE id IN($idafectades) group by idpol";

But I'm looking for something like:

id, idpol, count_idpol (number of times that each idpol's value appears in the group of rows)
1,  1000,  3
2,  1000,  3
3,  1002,  1
4,  1003,  2
5,  1003,  2
6,  1000,  3

Thanks

Comment: You want a windowed partition using the `over` syntax.

Comment: @xQbert Not in MySQL.

Comment: Apparently not: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way without using a windowed set.  Generate a set of data containing the counts grouped by the IDPOL, then join it back to the base set of each ID and IDpol.

```
SELECT foo.id, foo.idpol, B.cnt
FROM foo 
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) cnt, IdPOL FROM Foo GROUP BY IDPOL) B
 on Foo.IDPOL = B.IDPOL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f3df/7/0)